# updated a div inside a while loop

Tags: javascript

I have a class like so

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.oldEnough = 30;
    }

    celebrate(div) {
        let currentAge = 0;

        while(!this.isOldEnough(currentAge)) {
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                currentAge = currentAge + 1;
                div.innerHTML = `age is ${count} years old`;
            }, 100);
        }

        div.innerHTML = `Happy birthday ${this.name}!`;


        //clearInterval(timer);
    }

    isOldEnough(age) {
        return age === this.oldEnough;
    }
}

const jc = new Person('John', 0);
jc.celebrate(document.querySelector('#greeting'));
```

Of course, the `div` is not updated while the `while` loop which is why I am here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you clear the timer, the while will be done and the timer will be cleared before the 100ms are over

Comment: Any errors in console?

Comment: ok, I commented out the `clearTimer` command. Still no dice. No errors. In fact, as far as I can tell, the while loop is running because the browser is hanging

Comment: What's `currentAge`? Also FYI, `timer` won't be defined outside of that while block.

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but why not define the lambda as a generator function and yield?

Comment: I'm getting `ReferenceError: currentAge is not defined`. I updated your question with a snippet to show you this.

Comment: You have few mistakes https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/52/

Comment: yeah, I fixed the `currentAge` error

Comment: And now the snippet is breaking the page...

Comment: @NenadVracar your jsfiddle code works, thanks, but I need to use a `while` loop. The code I've shown above is pseudocode, the actual code has too many other things to show it here

Comment: @Andy of course the snippet makes the page hang because my snippet is wrong. That is why I am here :)

Comment: It didn't hang before you edited it :) It merely errored.

Comment: You could use generator https://jsfiddle.net/sfu9kt5h/53/

Comment: @NenadVracar your `generator` suggestion did the trick. Please post it as an answer so I can mark it as the correct answer. Next up, I have to go learn what the heck this `generator` is. I've never seen it until right now! Many thank!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `while` loop you could use generator inside `try...finally` block and call the iterator with `setInterval`

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.oldEnough = 30;
  }

  celebrate(div) {
    let self = this;

    function* count() {
      try {
        while (!self.isOldEnough()) {
          yield div.innerHTML = `age is ${self.age++} years old`;
        }
      } finally {
        div.innerHTML = `Happy birthday ${self.name}!`;
        clearInterval(timer);
      }
    }

    let it = count();
    let timer = setInterval(() => it.next(), 100)
  }

  isOldEnough() {
    return this.age === this.oldEnough;
  }
}

const jc = new Person('John', 0);
jc.celebrate(document.querySelector('#greeting'));
```

```html
<div id="greeting"></div>
```

Comment: this was a surprisingly difficult task (for me). In the process, I learned about generator and `yield`. Thanks @NenadVracar, and also thanks to @enfyve who also suggested the same, but didn't provide code :)

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use while loop, using  only interval you can achieve this

```
celebrate(div) {
  let currentAge = 0;


  const timer = setInterval(() => {
      currentAge = currentAge + 1;
      if (this.isOldEnough(currentAge)) {
          clearInterval(timer);
      }
      div.innerHTML = `age is ${count} years old`;
  }, 100);


  div.innerHTML = `Happy birthday ${this.name}!`;


  //clearInterval(timer);
}
isOldEnough(age) {
  return age === this.oldEnough;
}
```

Comment: see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183692/punkish) above. I've shown pseudocode here. In my actual code, which is considerably more complicated, I do need to use a while loop because it is doing much more than just incrementing a counter

Comment: what else you are doing?

Comment: @punkish yeah, I don't think we can help you in that case without seeing the full code -- you will probably have to change the way you are approaching some other things. JavaScript is going to continue evaluating that while loop regardless of what the interval is doing. That's why you're having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.oldEnough = 30;
    }

    celebrate(div) {   
            const timer = setInterval(() => {
                if(!this.isOldEnough(this.age)){
                    this.age++;
                    console.log(this.name + ' is ' + this.age + ' years old ')
                }
                else{
                    clearInterval(timer);
                }
            }, 100);

        console.log('Happy birthday ' + this.name)
    }

    isOldEnough(age) {
        return age === this.oldEnough;
    }
}
```

I think that's what you're after. Your constructor wasn't working because the [proper syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is `constructor(...)`, and you should just try to take advantage of the fact that `.setInterval()` [takes a function as its first parameter.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) If you have other conditions that must change according to whether the person 'is old enough', you can likely just put them in the if statement's `{}`.

Anyway, hope this helps.